# karma-typescript: import JS file with Async keyword

Tags: async-await, karma-jasmine, ecmascript-2017, karma-typescript

I'm using karma-typescript, with this karma config file :

```
karmaTypescriptConfig: {
  compilerOptions: {
    target: "es5",
    lib: ["dom", "es2015", "es2017"]
  },
  bundlerOptions: {
    transforms: [require("karma-typescript-es6-transform")()]
  }
},
```

In my spec files, I have this code :

```
import {} from './local/lib.js'
```

In my lib.js, I have this code :

```
async function() {}
```

When executing my tests with `npm test`, I have this error :

```
ERROR [source-reader.karma-typescript] Error parsing code: Unexpected token (X:Y) in /local/lib.js
```

If I remove the `async` keyword, everything is alright.

How can I edit my karma config file to fix the error ?

Comment: We ran into a similar issues. Do you know a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

According to an issue in the Github of the `karma-typescript` package (https://github.com/monounity/karma-typescript/issues/344), there is an undocumented flag which may help you test code which contains ES2017 code:

```
karmaTypescriptConfig: {
  compilerOptions: {
    target: "es5",
    lib: ["dom", "es2015", "es2017"]
  },
  bundlerOptions: {
    acornOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 8,
    },
    transforms: [require("karma-typescript-es6-transform")()]
  }
},
```

This flag made appear our issues with the `async` keyword. However, there is still an issue with the spread syntax (`...array`) in our code, even using this flag. If anyone knows an answer how to also fix that, I will happily extend my answer.